# How to mock structs with interdependent interface methods

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, mocking, go-interface

I am having trouble writing unit tests in Go for a rather common use-case/pattern.

Imagine, if you will, something like this:

```
package main

type Resource struct {
    name string
}

type ResourceManager interface {
    GetResource(id string) (*Resource, error)
    GetAllResources() ([]*Resource, error)
}

type ResourceManagerImpl struct {
}

func (r *ResourceManagerImpl) GetResource(id string) (*Resource, error) {
    resource := &Resource{}
    var err error

    // fetch resource.
    // ...

    return resource,  err
}

func (r *ResourceManagerImpl) GetAllResources() ([]*Resource, error) {
    var resources []*Resource
    var err error

    // for _, id := range ids {
    //  resource = r.GetResource(id)
    //  resources = append(resources, resource)
    // }

    return resources, err
}
```

It's a common pattern to have the `GetAllResources` invoke `GetResource` repeatedly as-needed.

I can use `gomock` or `testify` to test all permutations of `GetResource`. But, when testing `GetAllResource`, I'd like to mock `GetResource`. Otherwise, testing would become sort-of-a nightmare. This is how one would do it in `easymock` or `mockito` in case of Java using partial mocks. But, it's not clear how the same could be achieved in Golang.

Specifically, I couldn't find how to partially mock the `struct`. Most suggestions revolve around breaking such `struct`s but in this case, the `struct` is already at its bare minimum. It seems like a fair ask to not break the `ResourceManager` interface (into single and multi) for the sake of testing as that would not make much sense and would be kludgy at best and wouldn't scale well as more such methods make into the interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I deal with this kind of situation:

```
func (r *ResourceManagerImpl) GetAllResources() ([]*Resource, error) {
   return getAllResources(r)
}


func getAllResources(r ResourceManager) ([]*Resource,error) {
  ...
}
```

Then you test `getAllResources` instead of `GetAllResources` with a mocked `r`.  If you have a situation where `GetAllResources` is called from the code and you have to mock `GetAllResources`, you can do:

```
var getAllResources=func(r ResourceManager) ([]*Resource,error) {
...
}
```

And assign getAllResources to a test instance.

Comment: Looks like this is the best we could do. The resulting code still has redundant pieces, but it works. That would do for now.